# Selecting option from dropdown menu using Selenium; Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I need to select an element from a dropdown list. I'm using Selenium, but I'm having difficulty selecting the dropdown list itself to select from the available options and keep receiving an error "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:". I've tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('mysite.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xpath-example"]').click()
select.select_by_visable_text('option 1')
```

Comment: Can you include the html code in question and check if it's under any iframes or shadow roots. Also you never used select correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xpath-example"]')
sel = Select(elem)

sel.select_by_index(1)
sel.select_by_visible_text("option 1")
```

You need to find the elem and put it into the Select first of all. Then try one of the two options.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using by xpath click() action with:

`//*[@id="x"]/option[1]`

something like:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="x"]/option[1]').click()`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: first, you may want find_element**s** which returns a list as opposed to find element which returns an object.

Additionally, Because the element which you are trying to access may become visible at an unknown time, you *could* employ use of a timed wait, which (by your code) would always wait 10 seconds. Or you could make use of the webdriverwait function which would wait only until it was visible (which could be 2,3 or any time up to a timeout which you define)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('mysite.com')


try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="xpath-example"]')))
    item = elem.select_by_visible_text('option 1')
except:
    print("Couldn't find elem")
    pass
```